# Android get custom ringtone for a contact group

Tags: android

I need to determine the custom ringtone for a given contact group.

I can do this successfully to get the custom ringtone of a contact by using the following query:

```
Uri queryUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(callerNumber));

String[] columns = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CUSTOM_RINGTONE };    

Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(queryUri, columns, null, null, null);
```

But I can't find out how to determine the custom ringtone for a contact group.

Do you know how this can be done?

Thanks in advance!